# How to disable going from current form to others

Tags: c#

I'd like to disable going to other - same project - forms when I am working in a specific form.

I have seen that in some Windows application, when you click on other form it play a sound and nothing happens.

I have done this but didn't work :

```
public form2()
{
   form1.Enable = false;
}
```

Comment: You're looking for modal forms: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39wcs2dh(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for a `modal` form which is a window that needs to be closed before you can use the other forms. Use the [Form.ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method when you want to create a modal window otherwise use [Form.Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd.aspx).

(More information on `Modal` and `Modeless` windows [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)).

In your case, you'd open `Form2` like this:

```
form2.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 3):

`yourForm.ShowDialog();` will do the trick!

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx)